# how to plot histogram and bar chart using for loop and display them together?

Tags: python, charts, histogram

I want to plot histogram for numerical data and bar chart for categorical data. I have classified the data type already stored in `types`.

I'm not sure how to put the `plt.hist()` and `plt.bar()` into my for loop so that there will be 2 histogram (one for age and another for saving) displayed together side by side. Same goes to the categorical data, I want the 2 bar chart for 2 categorical data (gender and job). The code able to count the frequency of data also in order to plot histogram.

Which means at the end, I will have 4 chart, 2 are histogram and 2 are bar chart will show out all together side by side.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# first data is age
# 2nd data is gender
# third data is saving
# 4th data is job

data = np.array([[11, "male",1222,"teacher"],[23,"female",333,"student"],
                 [15,"male",542,"security"],[23,"male",4422,"farmer"],[25,"female",553,"farmer"],
                 [22, "male", 221, "teacher"],[27, "male", 333, "agent"],[11, "female", 33, "farmer"]])

# type of the data above
types = ["num","cat","num","cat"]
idx1 = []
idx2 = []
for index, _type in enumerate(types):
    if _type == 'num':
        idx1.append(index)
    else:
        idx2.append(index)

mean = []
std = []
for i in idx1:
    mean.append(np.mean(data[:,i].astype("float32")))
    std.append(np.std(data[:,i].astype("float32")))

print("mean: {}".format(mean))
print("std: {}".format(std))

mode = []
for i in idx2:
    mode.append(stats.mode(data[:,i]))
print("mode: {}".format([sub[0][0] for sub in mode]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will let you figure out the details of the plot as well as how to customize them, but my suggestion would be to turn it into a DataFrame object instead.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [11, 23, 15, 23, 25, 22, 27,11],
                     'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
                     'Saving': [1222, 333, 542, 4422, 553, 221, 333, 333],
                     'Occupation': ['teacher', 'student', 'security', 'farmer', 'farmer', 'teacher', 'agent', 'farmer']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Plot Data
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.hist(data['Age'], edgecolor = 'k')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.hist(data['Saving'], edgecolor = 'k')
plt.show()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
data['Gender'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
data['Occupation'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! However, I want to simplify the coding (plot in the loop), that's why I didn't use the code above. I hope the code able to create the graph inside the for loop because if the amount of data is big, then it doesn't make sense to plot one by one. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Seems like a lot of looping to me. How much data are we talking about?

Comment: The actual data consist of 16 features with 11700 samples. So there are a lot if I want to generate bar chart and histogram for 16 features one by one.